# PhoneGap Build won't load jQuery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm making an app that finds restaurants, and it works perfectly in PhoneGap Desktop, but when I use PhoneGap build to package it into an apk, the jQuery won't load, and I get a full scrollable page instead of individual jQuery pages. It might be an issue with the whitelist, but I've changed stuff and no joy. I can't link too much of the content because of intellectual property and such, but it's a generic jQuery Mobile structure. How do I make the jQuery load correctly?

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vegging Out</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fooStyle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        jQuery Mobile pages
        <script src="js/restaurantDatabase.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Vegging Out</name>

    <description>
        Vegging Out
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Tanya Branagan
    </author>
    <!-- PhoneGap person said to add CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' code.jquery.com">

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <!--
        Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
        <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
    -->

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.
        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->
    <!-- Hopefully will fix jQuery problem-->
    <access origin="*"/>
    <access origin="code.jquery.com" subdomains="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*.code.jquery.com/*" />


    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>



</widget>
```

Comment: What does your Content Security Policy meta tag look like?

Comment: For starters, your content security policy meta tags are in the config.xml, when they should be in head of the index.html. Also, you really only need one meta tag, so you can combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content security policy tag is necessary to indicate that your app has permission to load the script from code.jquery.com. As I mentioned in my comment, you don't need two meta tags for this, so you can combine them like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://code.jquery.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

It needs to be put in the header of the index.html and not in the config.xml.

Also, you might consider downloading JQuery and including it in your project locally instead.

Comment: I do have jQuery locally in the project. I tried downloading jQuery Mobile and doing the same, but when I export the project to an apk, it just loads to a white screen. I've just tried it again now, and same thing. I really don't understand why.

Comment: A white page is a pretty common symptom of a number of different loading issues with Phonegap Build. My guess is that the problem you're actually facing has to do with the plugins. PGB requires a different syntax for plugin definition in the config.xml than the command line version does. For example, here's the definition of the whitelist plugin from my working project:

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

Comment: Mine was created with command-line, but I have a config.xml tweaked to work with Phonegap build, so that plugin definition will work fine with PGB.

Here's a link to Adobe's Phonegap Build blog where they describe the most recent updates to the PGB plugin definition syntax in great detail.

http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/

Comment: I got it to work! I copied all the files to a blank directory structure that I made a while ago, the only change I'm aware of was putting the config file in the root, and in the www folder as well. No idea why that worked or if that was what worked, or if I should have even done that. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)